# PHP: Trying to ind key by value in multidimensional array but not working like it should

Tags: php, arrays

I've a stupid question but I don't get it. I've this array here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1509
            [1] => 1597
        )

)
```

What I need to do is to get the `key` by the value in my multidimensional array. The first array is always `0` I don't have anymore arrays after this. So I just need to check the `parent -> child` array.

At the moment I'm doing this here but it don't works:

```
$key = array_search( 1509, $array[0], true );
```

Key is always empty..

Comment: I just did this in a php sandbox site and got an answer. Here is my shared example on  [PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/99056ecb0ad53d99e2ba65636f0286cc22bcc533). Without seeing your code what you state is correct in in application.

Comment: This works just fine for me:
$array = array(array(1509, 1597));
$key = array_search(1509,  $array[0], true);

Comment: up and running.... https://3v4l.org/WOQEb

Comment: How **exactly** are you verifying that _"key is always empty"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for bringing me on the right way. The problem is that because of the true at the end I said be strict so it don't checks just the value, it checks the variable type too and I'm passing a variable here which is a int from type string. So strange but ok.

```
$key = array_search( (int) $var, $array[0], true );
```

Comment: So in other words, the code in your question does not match your actual code

Comment: Yes looks like your'e right. I've passed the variable via POST as a int before so I thought an int will come out on the other side. Thought it doesn't matter. Sorry. Voted for closing too.

Comment: FYI, all request input values (ie `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`) are strings.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not empty.  Assuming your array structure is as you say it is most likely what's happening is that you are not casting the output.

Try the following:

`exit((string)$k);`

Just to point out that this is to prove that what you are trying to do works.  No need to cast in normal scenario.